# The program just stops running once i click the signinButton and exits with Process finished with exit code -1073740791 (0xC0000409)

Tags: python, pyqt6

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QApplication, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QLabel, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QMdiArea,
    QTableWidgetItem, QStackedWidget
)
from PyQt6 import uic
import sys


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(r"C:\Users\csc\Documents\Rentour\front.ui", self)
        self.show()
        # define widgets
        self.button = self.findChild(QPushButton, "signinButton")
        self.signinButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenSignUp)


    def OpenSignUp(self):
        Sign_Up = Second()
        widget.addWidget(Sign_Up)
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class Second(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Second, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(r"C:\Users\csc\Documents\Rentour\signpopup.ui", self)
        # define widgets
        self.button = self.findChild(QPushButton, "SubmitSignButton")
        self.SubmitSignButton.clicked.connect(self.SignUpSave)

    def SignUpSave(self):

        email =self.EmailLine.text()
        phoneno =self.PhonenoLine.text()
        name =self.NameLine.text()
        password = self.PasswordLine.text()
        print(password)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = UI()
widget = QStackedWidget()
widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
widget.show()
app.exec()
```

this is my code. Am trying to create a login/signup page. So when i click the signinButton, i want it to load the ui for the page which will have a bunch of line edits whose inputs im attempting to store in variables.

The ui files were made using qt designer and and i made this file from scratch. I also referred code with Hala(Youtuber). I Am trying to create a login/signup page. So when i click the signinButton, i want it to load the ui for the page which will have a bunch of line edits whose inputs im attempting to store in variables.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `OpenSignUp` function.  The line `widget.addWidget(Sign_Up)` is not a valid command for a couple of reasons.

Also Sign_Up varable is holding a newly constructed QMainWindow, which are meant to be top level widgets and shouldn't be added to a layout.

It isn't totally clear what you are trying to achieve, but I am going to assume that you are trying to launch a secondary sign in window, In which case you want to use the open() method to launch the new window.

For example:

```
def OpenSignUp(self):
    self.Sign_Up = Second()
    self.Sign_Up.open()
```

Since you are using a stacked widget it is also possible that your goal is to simply switch to a different widget in the same window. In which case your `Second` class should probably just be a standard `QWidget`, and not a `QMainWindow`. and your stacked widget should be set as the central widget of your `UI` class.

So that would probably look something like this:

```
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import (
    QMainWindow, QApplication, QDialog, QDialogButtonBox, QLabel, QTextEdit, QPushButton, QMessageBox, QMdiArea,
    QTableWidgetItem, QStackedWidget
)
from PyQt6 import uic
import sys


class UI(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(UI, self).__init__()
        # uic.loadUi(r"C:\Users\csc\Documents\Rentour\front.ui", self)
        self.widget = QStackedWidget()
        self.widget.addWidget(mainwindow)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)
        self.Sign_Up = Second()
        self.widget.addWidget(self.Sign_Up)
        # define widgets
        self.button = self.findChild(QPushButton, "signinButton")
        self.signinButton.clicked.connect(self.OpenSignUp)


    def OpenSignUp(self):
        self.widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex()+1)

class Second(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Second, self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi(r"C:\Users\csc\Documents\Rentour\signpopup.ui", self)
        # define widgets
        self.button = self.findChild(QPushButton, "SubmitSignButton")
        self.SubmitSignButton.clicked.connect(self.SignUpSave)

    def SignUpSave(self):

        email =self.EmailLine.text()
        phoneno =self.PhonenoLine.text()
        name =self.NameLine.text()
        password = self.PasswordLine.text()
        print(password)

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainwindow = UI()
mainwindow.show()
app.exec()
```

Except you will need to rearrange the .ui file for `UI` class so that it is applied on top of the stacked widget as well.